# Tree leaf traversal in Prolog

Tags: prolog, prolog-defaulty

I experience some issues when I'm training prolog exercises,the problem below is,

The predicate defines what it means to be a tree, and can be used to test whether a term is a tree:

```
tree(t(L,R)) :- tree(L), tree(R).

tree(T) :- T\=t(_ , _).
```

By using this predicate you can find an element in a tree, (called a leaf):

```
leaf(t(L,R),E) :- leaf(L,E);  leaf(R,E).

leaf(T,T) :- T\=t(_ , _).
```

So here have two problem, first is write predicate `elements/2` that produces a list of the elements as they are found in the leafs of a tree in the first argument in a left-to-right order!

The second is write a predicate same `content/2` that succeeds exactly when two trees contain the same elements in the same order! Duplicates are significant.

Hope can get anyone good at prolog can help me, thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you made any attempt at all to writing these predicates that you want? If you examine all of the results of `leaf/2` when you run it, what do you observe in terms of the order of the results?

Comment: Use a cleaner representation! As is, you state "everything not unifiable with `t(_,_)` is a valid tree / leaf".

Comment: imo, elements/2 is just a findall/3, and content/2 just a join between elements/2

Comment: `elements(Tree, Elements) :- findall( E, leaf(Tree, E), Elements ).` and `content(Tree1, Tree2) :- elements(Tree1, E), elements(Tree2, E).`.

Comment: hi lurker,thanks i think this is the final answer.

Comment: hi luker,may i ask some other questions? about draw graphs represented these prolog terms:

Comment: To expand on @repeat's comment, it's hard to imagine how you can use `tree/1` to gain information about anything since it will unify with any term at all. Perhaps your second rule for it should be `tree(T) :- atom(T).`?

Comment: hi lurker,according your answer i make some exercises, tree(Leaf) :- Leaf \= tree(_,_).
tree(tree(L,R)) :- tree(L), tree(R).
Define a predicate sameleafs/2 that succeeds exactly when the set of leafs of two trees coincide!   my answer is sameleafs(left,right).
sameleafs(tree(Y,L1,R1),tree(Y,R2,L2)):-
sameleafs(L1,L2), sameleafs(R1,R2).   does it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `tree/1` and `leaf/1` are *de**faulty***<sup>[1](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/papers/PDF/tutorial.pdf),2</sup>!
Why not use a cleaner representation like this?

```
is_tree(leaf(_)).
is_tree(bin(L,R)) :-
   is_tree(L),
   is_tree(R).
```

Note that:

- `is_tree/1` is more versatile than `tree/1` and `leaf/1`: it can *generate* as well as *test* trees—and even *do a little of both* (if the argument is partially instantiated).
- `is_tree/1` *never* gives logically unsound answers—no matter which "mode" it is used in.

Some sample uses of `is_tree/1`:

```
?- is_tree(T).                                   % generate
  T  = leaf(_A)
; T = bin(leaf(_A),leaf(_B))
; T = bin(leaf(_A),bin(leaf(_B),leaf(_C)))
; T = bin(leaf(_A),bin(leaf(_B),bin(leaf(_C),leaf(_D))))
...

?- is_tree(bin(leaf(1),bin(leaf(2),3))).         % test
false.

?- is_tree(bin(leaf(1),bin(leaf(2),leaf(3)))).   % test
true.

?- T = bin(bin(leaf(1),2),_), is_tree(T).        % do both (or at least try)
false.

?- T = bin(bin(leaf(1),leaf(2)),_), is_tree(T).  % do both
T = bin(bin(leaf(1),leaf(2)),leaf(_A))
T = bin(bin(leaf(1),leaf(2)),bin(leaf(_A),leaf(_B)))
T = bin(bin(leaf(1),leaf(2)),bin(leaf(_A),bin(leaf(_B),leaf(_C)))) 
...
```

Coming back to your question on how to implement `elements/2` and `content/2`... **Use [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg)!**

```
leaves(leaf(E))  --> [E].
leaves(bin(L,R)) --> leaves(L), leaves(R).

same_content(A,B) :-
   phrase(leaves(A),Ls),
   phrase(leaves(B),Ls).
```

Sample query:

```
?- same_content(bin(leaf(1),bin(leaf(2),leaf(3))), 
                bin(bin(leaf(1),leaf(2)),leaf(3))).
true.
```

---

<sup>**Footnote 1:** This [rock-solid treatise on teaching Prolog](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/papers/PDF/tutorial.pdf) discusses many common obstacles, including *defaultyness*.


**Footnote 2:** In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7231974/4609915) @mat explains on how defaultyness in Prolog impedes declarative debugging and reasoning.</sup>